# Trigger modal on form ngsubmit?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have an input and a button inside a form.

I want to type in the input and hit enter, submitting the input content and triggering a modal to open, displaying the results. I don't have any idea how to trigger a modal on ng-submit without getting custom/hacky. Is there an understood method for doing it?

Currently:

```
<form>
    <div ng-show="thirdPhase" class="input-group animated fadeIn">
        <input type="text" class="form-control finderBar" placeholder="City, State..." autofocus>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#searchModal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

And Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="searchModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Search Results</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        TEST SEARCH MODAL
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried putting the typical modal trigger attributes in the form element, but that simply triggers the modal as soon as you click on the input inside the form.

Comment: why don't you use `ui-bootstrap` modal popup, which has better way to open it programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming you dont want a special button for modal to pop up from, and just ngSubmit to lead the way(and without getting hacky), you need to modify your html to something like this,

```
    <div ng-controller="whateverYouWant" data-target="#searchModal" data-toggle="modal">
        <form ng-submit="submit()">
            <div ng-show="thirdPhase" class="input-group animated fadeIn">
                <input type="text" class="form-control 
finderBar" placeholder="City, State..." autofocus>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Notice i removed `<button>` from HTML and put `data-target` and `data-modal` in `<div>` that has ng-controller.

Finally modify your script to something like this :

```
$scope.submit = function (){
 .
 . 
 .
 $('#searchModal').modal('show');
}
```

With this ,when the ng-submit finishes its task it automatically initializes the modal and you can use `ng-modal` to bind the data.

Checkout [Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Answer (score 1):

Here in below example, I have created my own modal directive.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
    <h1>Modal example</h1>
    <form ng-submit="toggleModal()">
        <div class="input-group animated fadeIn">
            <input type="text" class="form-control finderBar" placeholder="City, State..." autofocus>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Go!</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>

    <modal title="Search Results" visible="showModal">
        TEST SEARCH MODAL
    </modal>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', []);

mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showModal = false;
    $scope.toggleModal = function(){
        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    };
});

mymodal.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
          '<div class="modal-dialog">' + 
            '<div class="modal-content">' + 
              '<div class="modal-header">' + 
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' + 
              '</div>' + 
              '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
            '</div>' + 
          '</div>' + 
        '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace:true,
      scope:true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.title = attrs.title;

        scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
          if(value == true)
            $(element).modal('show');
          else
            $(element).modal('hide');
        });

        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
          });
        });

        $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
          });
        });
      }
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s9472gcj/

You can use `ui-bootstrap` as well as @Pankaj Parkar suggested.

For more information https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it's the best to use `angular-ui-bootstrap`.

Then you can create a factory for creating your modal and you can open the result modal from a method of your first `modalInstanceController`.

The factory in the demo is very basic and could be improved e.g. passing the controller name with the params to avoid the hard-coded controller name.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/74exww04/).

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .factory('modalFactory', function($uibModal) {
    return {
      open: function(size, template, params) {
        return $uibModal.open({
          animation: true,
          templateUrl: template || 'myModalContent.html',
          controller: 'ModalResultInstanceCtrl',
          size: size,
          resolve: {
            params: function() {
              return params;
            }
          }
        });
      }
    };
  })
  .controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, $log, $uibModal) {

    //$scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

    //$scope.animationsEnabled = true;

    $scope.open = function(size, template) {
      var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
          templateUrl: template || 'myModalContent.html',
          controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
          size: size
        });

      /*modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
        $scope.selected = selectedItem;
      }, function() {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
      });*/
    };

    $scope.toggleAnimation = function() {
      $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
    };

  });

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, modalFactory) {

  //$scope.searchTerm = term;

  $scope.ok = function() {
    modalFactory.open('lg', 'result.html', {searchTerm: $scope.searchTerm});
    //$uibModalInstance.close($scope.searchTerm);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalResultInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, params) {

  $scope.searchTerm = params.searchTerm;

  $scope.ok = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.close($scope.searchTerm);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Demo form submit:
        <br/>
        <form ng-submit="ok()">
          <div class="input-group animated fadeIn">
            <input type="text" class="form-control finderBar" ng-model="searchTerm" placeholder="City, State..." autofocus>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="ok()">Go!</button>
        </span>
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="result.html">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         You searched for: {{searchTerm}}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
      </div>
    </script>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="toggleAnimation()">Toggle Animation ({{ animationsEnabled }})</button>-->
    <div ng-show="searchTerm">searchTerm from a modal: {{ searchTerm }}</div>
  </div>

</div>
```